# How to create an infinite Sign Trajectory using CSS animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I want to create infinite symbol animation using div.
What animation needs to be done on the div to achieve this.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you mean 'sin' not 'sign'

Comment: I would think of [animatio()](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp) and just create a path where the absolute div has to go.

Comment: I mean I want to create this movement of div using css animation.

Comment: @nkmol : If you know how to can you explain or create this movement in css animation.

Comment: Does it have to be a `<div>`? HTML5 `<canvas>` animation would probably be a better solution to this problem.

Comment: @andyb : Actually I was trying to do it with the help of css animation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well for example in this picture :

[image]

All the purple are dots where your 'ball' should go through.
You can see each dot as a key-frame. There are 16 dots (2 same in the center) in 100% time. That means every key-frame is 6.25% of the total time.

The ball is easially created with CSS:

```
.ball
{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 40px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Basically you define each dots left and top position.

Now i've made a really little example, because i haven't much time ;p
But i hope you get the idea what i'm trying to do: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uVFd3/)**

More info about animation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp).

### Update

I couldn't let this answer stand without a working example. So hereby:

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uVFd3/5/)

*As you can see the transitions aren't that smooth. How more path points you add, how more smooth the animation curves get.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply but your animation doesn't seem to be like infinity symbol.

Comment: It actually is, i made the animation 20s and only created the first 2 dots :P [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uVFd3/1/) you can see the unfinished animation in 2 seconds. If you let the animation end where it started, it will go infinite in a loop.

Comment: Actually I want to create it with only one dot.

Comment: I geuss you want a precoded animation? Well how does the ball know where to go when there is only 1 point? Sorry but i can't help you further :p

Answer (score 4):

Tried a different approach. Still all just CSS3 animation.

Two balls running along an orbit twice. One clockwise and the other one counter-clockwise. Both orbits (divs) are positioned seamlessly next to each other. Until the first one completes his run, the other one is hidden. When they meet in the middle, the first one hides and the second one starts his run.

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/leymannx/LWk74/
tested on Chrome 31, Firefox 26, Safari 7 and IE 10 & 11
(cross browser compatibility incorporated in the fiddle)

```
#left {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;

  animation: animationLeft 5s linear infinite;
}

#right {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 350px;

  animation: animationRight 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animationLeft {
  0%    { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(100px); }
  50%   { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(100px); visibility: hidden; }
  100%  { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(100px); visibility: hidden; }
}

@keyframes animationRight {
  0%    { transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(100px); visibility: hidden; }
  50%   { transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(100px); visibility: hidden; }
  100%  { transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(100px); }
}
```

More information on animating circular paths exemplified with planets can be found [here](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/03/03/animating-circular-paths-using-css3-transitions/). There also `rotate(360deg)` and `translateX(100px)` is explained very well.

Comment: This is the best attempt I've got.

Answer (score 2):

So I have three options for you. One is that you basically tranform the origin to right side, depending upon the size of the dot and rotate it by 360degrees and when it completes the rotation tranform origin to left of original image and rotate counter clockwise to 0degrees.
This is a pen for that. It is still a little bit jittery but I am working on it.

[Codepen](http://cdpn.io/gGriy)

Now second option is a bit complicated but will give you a better animation. Four steps for it.

1. Translate or move the dot diagonally upwards to right.
2. Transform the origin diagonally (downwards right) and rotate it clockwise by some degrees.
3. Transform origin again to 50% 50% and translate to upwards left.
4. Repeat step 2 with rotation in counter clockwise direction.

Third is even more complicated and cannot be achieved by only css. You need to use javascript. What you can do is you can go actually come up with an equation for infinity symbol also called [Lemniscate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate) and calculate the position relative to your current position and animate it.

Comment: it gets stop for second when it takes on loop but it very much accurate. Thanks for trying. If it's possible please try to make it flawless.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon this and created a small website that converts any SVG path into a series of points.

For example if you want to animate [this](http://imgh.us/anim_8.svg) SVG just read the contents and paste it into a small [tool](http://jsbin.com/geragixibi/1) i developed:

```
<svg width="102px" height="52px" viewBox="0 0 102 52" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>Line</title>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="square">
        <path d="M26,1 C38.5,1 51,26 51,26 C51,26 63.5,51 76,51 C88.5,51 101,38.5 101,26 C101,13.5 88.5,1 76,1 C63.5,1 51,26 51,26 C51,26 38.5,51 26,51 C13.5,51 1,38.5 1,26 C1,13.5 13.5,1 26,1 Z" id="Line" stroke="#FF3737"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The code goes in the first textfield and the inverse number of points into the second textfield (1 = many points, 10 = not so many points etc..).

It outputs a keyframe animation series which you can use to animate your point: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6xaanbr6)